# Subtotals in grouped row

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using jQuery Datatables and in my table I'm grouping by the values in the first column of the table and displaying all data with a matching first column in groups. I have 'Subtotal' rows within each of my groups that I would like to be displayed inline with the grouped row. Here is an example of what my table looks like now:

[image: Example of how my datatable looks now]

I want to get the cells from the 'Subtotal' row and put them in the grouped row. Like so:

[image: How I'd like my datatable to look]

Here's the current code for my datatable:

```
$('#table').dataTable( {
      "bFilter": true,
      "aaSorting": [[ 5, "desc" ]],
                "aaSortingFixed": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
      "columnDefs": [
          { "visible": false, "targets": 0 }
      ],
      "pageLength": 50,
                "aoColumns": [
        null,null,            { "sSortDataType": "num-html", "sType": "formatted-num" },
        { "sSortDataType": "num-html", "sType": "formatted-num" },
        { "sSortDataType": "num-html", "sType": "formatted-num" },
        { "sSortDataType": "num-html", "sType": "formatted-num" },
        { "sSortDataType": "num-html", "sType": "formatted-num" },
        { "sSortDataType": "num-html", "sType": "formatted-num" },
        { "sSortDataType": "num-html", "sType": "formatted-num" },
        { "sSortDataType": "num-html", "sType": "formatted-num" },
        { "sSortDataType": "num-html", "sType": "formatted-num" },
        { "sSortDataType": "num-html", "sType": "formatted-num" },
        { "sSortDataType": "num-html", "sType": "formatted-num" },
        { "sSortDataType": "num-html", "sType": "formatted-num" },
        { "sSortDataType": "num-html", "sType": "formatted-num", "visible": false },
        { "sSortDataType": "num-html", "sType": "formatted-num", "visible": false },
        { "sSortDataType": "num-html", "sType": "formatted-num", "visible": false },
        { "sSortDataType": "num-html", "sType": "formatted-num", "visible": false }
      ],
      "sDom": "CTlfrt<'container'<'pull-left'i><'pull-right'p>>",
      "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
                "drawCallback": function ( settings ) {
        var api = this.api();
        var rows = api.rows( {page:'current'} ).nodes();
        var last=null;

        api.column(0, {page:'current'} ).data().each( function ( group, i ) {
            if ( last !== group ) {
                $(rows).eq( i ).before(
                    "<tr class='group'><td colspan='"+18+"' style='background:#bcbcbc !important;'>"+group+"</td></tr>"
                );

                last = group;
            }
        } );
      },
                "oLanguage": {
        "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page"
      },
      "oTableTools": {
        "sSwfPath": "/public/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
        "aButtons": [
          "copy",
          "print",
          "csv"
        ]
      },
    } );
```

What Javascript can I use to do this for me whenever the table is drawn? Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Oh, you want a javascript to apply it to your "dataTable" javascript object and you expect it will rearrange data in it so your grid will just show what is inside? So you don't need to change the grid. Is this what you want? It is clever! But it is not fair - you have data and you have grid-component. If you share what you already have it will be easy for us to help and for you to adopt the solution.

Comment: +1 @YevgeniyAfanasyev; a fiddle will go a long way.

Answer (score 2):

check fiddle (Subtotals in grouped row) :  [link][1]

http://jsfiddle.net/X5LB9/

```
enter code here
```

Comment: In that code the subtotals are being summed up within the JS, but I am already passing in the summed up data, I just want to make it part of the grouped row.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use [jqGrid: jQuery Grid Plugin](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)

Select example in left panel / Grouping / View Summary Row on Collapse

Answer (score 0):

I found this link useful to get solution : 
https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/20844/rowgroup-sum-and-total